# Multistage build deletes directories of previous stages?

Tags: node.js, docker

I've got this docker file, that's supposed to install usd_from_gltf (the first stage) and then run the nodejs server with access to the usd_from_gltf command. But when I run this, it seems the container directories get all deleted and overwritten by the other stage. How do I prevent this?

```
FROM leon/usd:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/ufg

# Configuration
ARG UFG_RELEASE="3bf441e0eb5b6cfbe487bbf1e2b42b7447c43d02"
ARG UFG_SRC="/usr/src/ufg"
ARG UFG_INSTALL="/usr/local/ufg"
ENV USD_DIR="/usr/local/usd"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${USD_DIR}/lib:${UFG_SRC}/lib"
ENV PATH="${PATH}:${UFG_INSTALL}/bin"
ENV PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:${UFG_INSTALL}/python"

# Build + install usd_from_gltf
RUN git init && \
    git remote add origin https://github.com/google/usd_from_gltf.git && \
    git fetch --depth 1 origin "${UFG_RELEASE}" && \
    git checkout FETCH_HEAD && \
    python "${UFG_SRC}/tools/ufginstall/ufginstall.py" -v "${UFG_INSTALL}" "${USD_DIR}" && \
    cp -r "${UFG_SRC}/tools/ufgbatch" "${UFG_INSTALL}/python" && \
    rm -rf "${UFG_SRC}" "${UFG_INSTALL}/build" "${UFG_INSTALL}/src"


FROM node:12

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Comment: Is this question different from similar ones asked here?

Comment: I have not found any similar.

Comment: you are not copying files from the previous stage via `COPY --from=STAGE FROM TO` https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds